# iPhone6でスクロールビューの中身のビューがスクロールビューの横幅と合わない

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

iOSアプリで[こちら](http://qiita.com/hirobe/items/2baf629b7807b4c0d10f)の記事を参考にしてスクロールビューを実装しています。

iOS7では問題なく動くのですが、iOS8 iPhone6ではビューの中身のスクロールする部分の横幅が親ビューよりも広くなってしまいました。

解決方法を知っていたら教えてください。

画像の青い部分がスクロールビューの中身、赤い部分がスクロールビューです。 
左が理想、右が現在です。

[image: イメージ説明]

Comment: 差し支えない範囲で構いませんので、該当部分のソースコードを記載しておくと有効な回答が得やすくなると思います。

Answer (score 2):

「UIScrollViewとその中身のViewの幅を等しい」という制約を張ることで実現できます
http://qiita.com/hirobe/items/2baf629b7807b4c0d10f

Answer (score 0):

赤い枠はUIScrollViewのframe、青い枠はUIScrollViewのcontentSizeに相当するかと思います。
何故意図しない動きになっているかは今の情報だけでは特定できませんが、frameやcontentSizeにどんな値を入れているのか、またはどんな値が入っているのかをNSLogして、何か思い当たるフシが無いかを探ってみてください。

Comment: すみません。自分でよくわかってなかったもので。
AutoLayoutを使ってスクロールする画面を作っています。
それで、UIScrollViewと中身のビューの幅を合わせるためにEqual widthをかけています。
それが、ios7のiPhone5では問題なく横幅が合うのですが、iOS8のiPhone6では横幅が合わないのです。
iPhone6でも横幅を合わせる方法を教えてください。

Comment: autolayoutは使ったことが無いので、すみませんが判りません。